# Use form elements in Email-Marketing

Tags: email, mailchimp

Is it okay to use form elements (text boxes, radio buttons, check boxes, buttons) in an email newsletter or is it still risky because a lot of clients do not support it?

What do you think? I would like to create a small form inside a newsletter to ask about the topic preferences of my recipients. Would you recomment to create a landingpage with a form instead?